# High number of Request Timeouts on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a fairly busy site which does around 10m views a month.

One of my app pools seemed to jam up for a few hours and I'm looking for some ideas on how to troubleshoot it..? I suspect that it somehow ran out of threads but I'm not sure how to determine this retroactively..? Here's what I know:

- The site never went 'down', but around 90% of requests started timing out.
- I can see a high number of "HttpException - Request timed out." in the log during the outage
- I can't find any SQL errors or code errors that would have caused the timeouts.
- The timeouts seem to have been site wide on all pages.
- There was one page with a bug on it which would have caused errors on that specific page.
- The site had to be restarted.

The site is ASP.NET C# 3.5 WebForms..

**Possibilities:**

1. ***Thread depletion:*** My thought is that the page causing the error may have somehow started jamming up the available threads?
2. ***Global code error:*** Another possibility is that one of my static classes has an undiscovered bug in it somewhere. This is unlikely as the this has never happened before, and I can't find any log errors for these classes, but it is a possibility.

***UPDATE***

I've managed to trace the issue now while it's occurring. The pages are being loaded normally but for some reason **WebResource.axd** and **ScriptResource.axd** are both **taking a minute to load**. In the performance counters I can see ASP.NET Requests Queued spikes at this point.

Comment: btw; there is no such thing as C# 3.5; I assume you mean C# 3.0 targeting .NET 3.5

Comment: Do you use threads/locks/mutex and more than one working pool ? Search for mutex lock.

Comment: Hi Aristos, yes this is definately an area I should investigate further. All my central thread locks have a 25ms bypass on them, eg. Monitor.TryEnter(_mylock, 25); But I might have missed something there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is Sam Saffron's [CPU analyzer tool](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2009/11/11/Diagnosing+runaway+CPU+in+a+Net+production+application), which should give an indication if there is something common that is happening too much / too long. In part because it doesn't involve any changes; just run it at the server.

After that, there are various other debugging tools available; we've found that [some very ghetto approaches](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/04/practical-profiling.html) can be insanely effective at seeing where time is spent (of course, it'll only work on the 10% of successful results).

You can of course just open the server profiling tools and drag in various .NET / IIS counters, which *may* help you spot some things.

Between these three options, you should be covered for:

- code dropping into a black hole and never coming out (typically threading related)
- code *running*, but too slowly (typically data access related)

Comment: Thanks Marc, appreciate the info. I've loaded up some performance counters for this now, but as you would guess, all counters are looking pretty normal now. Will keep them loaded if it occurs again.. Also, forgot to mention, CPU dropped to nothing during the outage..

Comment: @Dave if CPU is nothing, that *could* be mass-blocking (thread related errors), or could be data-access issues; both involve no CPU

Comment: Thanks Marc, yeah the low CPU does make it look that way. I think I can rule out the data-access side. I've encountered many of those through the years and know how to spot them quite well. Also can't pick up any SQL timeouts in the log, and static pages with no SQL where also timing out. So I think thread blocking is looking like the culprit here..

Comment: @Dave - thread blocking *tends* to be easy to spot with a polling-based profiler, as every time it asks what the thread is doing it'll be stuck waiting

Comment: I've located the main symptom now, for some reason my two .axd files are taking a minute to load..

Comment: @Dave - anything huge in them? are they large themselves?